# Perl - parse file text into hash

Tags: perl, parsing, hash

I want to parse a file text then to put it into a hash. My file looks like at :

```
key1 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val
key2 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val
key3 val
key4 val,val
key5 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val
```

My keys are before space and my values are the list of elements after the space and before each comma. I have some lines where there are not key because the values continue on few lines.

So I want a hash like that (i am most familiar in Python):

```
hash={'key1':[val,val,...],'key2':[val,val,...]}
```

My code : 
`

```
my %hashNames;
open INFILE, "./file.txt" or die $!;
my @temp = ();

while (my $line = <INFILE>)
{

    my @names = split /[\t,]/, $line;
    my $ID = $names[0];
    if ( $line =~ /\t/ )
    {

        my @temp=();
        for (my $i = 1; $i < @names; $i +=1)
        {
            push (@temp, $names[$i]);
        }

    }
    else
    {   

        for (my $i = 0; $i < @names; $i +=1)
        {
            push (@temp, $names[$i]);
        }       
    }
}`
```

Comment: show us what you've tried

Comment: If you know how to do it in Python, show us that please.

Comment: i think that i must read each lines and if there is a space i must create a new key and push the differents values (in a list) and if there is not space i must add the values at the previous key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here is that your records are terminated by "a newline that is not preceded by a comma". Unfortunately, the input record separator `$/` can't be set to a regex. This leaves three comfortable solutions:

1. Load the whole file to memory. This isn't as bad as it sounds, because we have the same amount of information in the hash later on. We can then `split /(?<!,)\n/` to get the actual records.

   ```
   my %hash = do {
     local $/; # set to undef, for slurp
     map {
       my ($key, $vals) = split /\s+/, $_, 2; # split on first whitespace, into two strings
       $key => [ split /\s*,\s*/, $vals ];    # return a list of a key and a value array
     } split /(?<!,)\n/, <FILE>;              # split the file into records
   };
   ```
2. We can write a `readline` substitute that buffers the input and can terminate lines with regexes.
3. We can think of the trailing comma as a line continuation character.

   ```
   my %hash;
   while(<FILE>) {
     $_ .= <FILE> while /,\n\z/;
     my ($key, $value) = split /\s+/, $_, 2;
     push @{ $hash{$key} }, split /\s*,\s*/, $value; # allow multiple occurrences of one key, simply append values to list.
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you very much for yout answer. how can i retrieve the keys and the values of the list?

Comment: @Tof I don't quite get that question. For a given `$key`, you can get the `@vals` like `@vals = @{ $hash{$key} }`. You need the `@{...}`, because that hash can only store a *reference* to the array, not the array *itself*, so we have to dereference it back to the array.

Comment: For example i would retrieve the array for a specific key for then scanning it.

Comment: @Tof How is that an example of anything? See `perldoc perldata` for information on basic perl structures.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that newlines no longer separate your records. So a way to handle it is to disable the invalid default input record separator `$/` and emulate a valid one:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
my $file;
{
    local $/;         # disable input record separator
    $file = <DATA>;   # entire file here now!
}

for my $line (split /^(?=\S+ )/m, $file) {  # records begin this way now
    $line =~ s/\n//g;                       # remove newlines
    my ($key, $val) = split ' ', $line, 2;  # divide into two fields
    $hash{$key} = [ split /,/, $val ];      # store the data
}

print Dumper \%hash;

__DATA__
key1 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val
key2 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val
key3 val
key4 val,val
key5 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val
```

**Explanations:**

- Splitting on `/^(?=\S+ )/m` using the `/m` modifier means `^` will now match newlines inside the string, which will emulate an input record separator.
- Splitting the string in two fields is done by adding a LIMIT 2 to the `split`
- We split directly into the hash by using an anonymous array `[ ... ]` with a split statement inside it.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parse%3A%3ARecDescent) module

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Parse::RecDescent;

our %hash;
my $p = Parse::RecDescent->new(q!
  hash: entry(s?)
  entry: key value(s /,/)  { $::hash{$item[1]} = [ @{ $item[2] } ] }
  key: /\S+/
  value: /([^,\n]|\\,])+/
!);
die "$0: failed to create parser" unless defined $p;

my $text = do {{ local $/; <DATA> }};
$p->hash($text) or die "$0: parse failed";

for (sort keys %hash) {
  print "$_ => val x ", scalar @{ $hash{$_} }, "\n";
}

__DATA__
key1 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val
key2 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val
key3 val
key4 val,val
key5 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val
```

Output:

```
key1 => val x 22
key2 => val x 22
key3 => val x 1
key4 => val x 2
key5 => val x 52
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
my %results;
my $key;
while(my $line = <INFILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    my @items = split(/, */, $line);
    $key = shift @items;
    $results{$key} = \@items;
}
```

Which works for the simple case except for your statement:

*I have some lines where there are not key because the values continue on few lines.*

To handle that, though, you'll have to explain how to detect whether the next line is a key or a value.  If you know, then you can put it in an if statement and use the previous key to add new values to the hash:

```
my %results;
my $key;
while(my $line = <INFILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    my @items = split(/, */, $line);
    my $tmpkey = shift @items;
    if (is_real_key($tmpkey)) {
        $key = shift @items;
        $results{$key} = \@items;
    } else {
        push (@{$results{$key}}, $tmpkey, @items);
    }
}
```

Comment: in fact i have values that continue over multiple lines and so there are not key.

Comment: Yeah, I handled that.  But you didn't say *how* you know when the values stop and a new key begins.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $res_hash = {};
my ($current_key, $values);
my $push_again;
while ( my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  push ( @{ $res_hash->{$current_key} }, split(/,/, $values) ) if ( $current_key and $values and ( index($line, ' ') > 0) );
  if ( index($line, ' ') > 0 ){
    $push_again = 0;
    ($current_key, $values) = split( /\s/, $line);    
  } else {
    $values .= $line;
    $push_again = 1;
  }

};
push ( @{ $res_hash->{$current_key} }, split(/,/, $values) ) if $push_again;

say "result:".Dumper($res_hash);



__DATA__
key1 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val
key2 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val
key3 val
key4 val,val
key5 val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,
val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val,val
```

Comment: You have a missing last record. You must push the buffer after the last loop iteration as well.

Comment: you're right, thx - however, I tend to like your solution more